# How to avoid dropdown menu hiding while click on checkbox inside the dropdown list items?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Need to avoid the dropdown menu hiding while clicking on 'checkbox' inside the dropdown list items. dropdown menu should hide when click outside of dropdown & dropdown toggle button area , also selected items value should load in dropdown toggle text area. please help, I am using react-bootstrap dropdown

```
 <Dropdown className="dropdown-groove">
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="outline-secondary " id="dropdown-basic">
          Select...
          <label className="dropdown-label">Dropdown label</label>
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
            {" "}
            <Form.Check
              className="checkbox-groove"
              inline
              label="Unselected"
              name="group1"
              type="checkbox"
            />{" "}
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">List Item 2</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">List Item 3</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-4">List Item 4</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-5">List Item 5</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-with-checkbox-nvw3hz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}` in `<Form.Check>...</Form.Check>`.
`e.stopPropagation()` in tag will help this tag prevent onClick event from parent.

Code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-with-checkbox-forked-88h9m6?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.scss";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Dropdown, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dropdown className="dropdown-groove">
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="outline-secondary " id="dropdown-basic">
          Select...
          <label className="dropdown-label">Dropdown label</label>
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">
            {" "}
            <Form.Check
              onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} //<=== Add here
              className="checkbox-groove"
              inline
              label="Unselected"
              name="group1"
              type="checkbox"
            />{" "}
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">List Item 2</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">List Item 3</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-4">List Item 4</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-5">List Item 5</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @PRANAV Use map to make code shotern. Here is code to load selected item: https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-with-checkbox-forked-6k4hpt

Comment: YA, but wanted to load checked items values as well,  there will be multiple List items with check boxes. :-(